# ActionBar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an android application where I use the ActionBar in NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS mode.

Currently, I am heavily using Fragments. So, that worked quite well for the displayed tabs. I am facing a design issue where I think I am going in the wrong direction.

MainActivity has three tabs. One tab in particular have bunch of navigations on it.

MainActivity

- Tab1
- Tab2
- Tab3 (This has buttons that should display different fragments based on what the user clicked)

The requirement is to keep the tabs always visible with the same text. So, I ended up creating bunch of activities that inherit from the MainActivity where I made the third tab content based on what the user clicked on.

This allowed me to sustain the content in a good flow  and keep the look consistent. However, It seems an overhead to create an activity.

I tried to leverage the FragmentManager and pushToStack. However, that route didn't seem to work.

I am relying on this interface ActionBar.TabListener to properly attach and detach the fragments based when the user clicks on the tab. That is good. However, the minute I introduce a different fragment that seemed problematic.

Hope That is clear and I am looking for the best advice.

I solved it by relying on the the following logic:

```
public class FragmentTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
    private String _fragmentClassName;
    private Context _context;
    private Fragment _fragment;
    private Boolean _cleanStack = true;

    public FragmentTabListener(Context context, String fragmentClassName,
            Boolean cleanStack)
    {
        _context = context;
        _fragmentClassName = fragmentClassName;
        _cleanStack = cleanStack;

    }

    public FragmentTabListener(Context context, String fragmentClassName)
    {
        this(context, fragmentClassName, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        cleanFragmentManagerStack();
        if (this._cleanStack)
        {
            ft.attach(_fragment);
        }
    }

    private void cleanFragmentManagerStack()
    {
        if (this._cleanStack)
        {
            FragmentManager mgr = ((Activity) _context).getFragmentManager();
            int backStackCount = mgr.getBackStackEntryCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < backStackCount; i++)
            {
                // Get the back stack fragment id.
                int backStackId = mgr.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getId();

                mgr.popBackStack(backStackId,
                        FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        if (_fragment == null)
        {
            _fragment = Fragment.instantiate(_context, _fragmentClassName);
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, _fragment);
        }
        else
        {
            ft.attach(_fragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        this.cleanFragmentManagerStack();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.detach(_fragment);

    }

}
```

Any action on my original fragment, I was adding a fragment to the current stack.

This worked. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need 3 fragments, each one of them in one tab, and in the 3rd tab you can have, inside that fragment, based on what user clicked, a different fragment inside (nested fragments are supported now). Maybe I didn't understand your problem correctly, if that's the case tell me.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am taking a look at it if it is supported in the support library. I'd like not lock myself in a newer API so i can have the app work for older models. 

Thanks,

Comment: I'm using the support library also for a similar thing. Actually as far as I know you can use only support fragments within a ViewPager.